# Find out MD5 salt when given starting value and encrypted end value

Tags: encryption, md5

Is there a method to find out the salt used when I have the starting value and the end encrypted value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking#Brute_force_attack).

There's not really any difference between cracking a single password and cracking a single salt/password combination.

Comment: Just as an aside, I wonder if anyone else finds the humor in the fact that "Luke" is suggesting to use the "force" ... :)

Answer (score 1):

The salt must be stored *somewhere*. Most of the time, the salt value is simply prepended to the encrypted value, so that the validation code has everything it needs to verify that a challenge password hashes to the same value.

On the other hand, it is possible that the salt is stored somewhere inaccessible, such as with the user profile information.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force or exploitation of known weaknesses is about it.

The thing is, you really *don't* know the starting value since what gets encrypted is the data concatenated with the salt.  Something along the lines of

```
md5hash($value.$salt);
```

In many cases (such as passwords) the salt is actually longer than the data being encrypted, so you actually only know a small part of the data going into the algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

Recommend you do not do it as it may be illegal activity in your state but you could always check the standards documentation for Message Digest 5 encryption.

Comment: He is asking about the salt not MD5